# Session don't work

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

Page One

```
$query_user1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE gruppo='$page' LIMIT $rand, 1");
        $estrai1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_user1);

        $id1 = $estrai1["id"];
        $name1 = $estrai1["name"];
        $surname1 = $estrai1["surname"];
        $img1 = $estrai1["img"];
        $voti1 = $estrai1["voti"];
        $_SESSION["code1"] = $code1;
        $_SESSION["voti1"] = $voti1;


        $query_user2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE gruppo='$page' LIMIT $rand1, 1");
        $estrai2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_user2);

        $id2 = $estrai2["id"];
        $code2 = $estrai2["code"];
        $name2 = $estrai2["name"];
        $surname2 = $estrai2["surname"];
        $img2 = $estrai2["img"];
        $voti2 = $estrai2["voti"];
        $_SESSION["code2"] = $code2;
        $_SESSION["voti2"] = $voti2;
        $_SESSION["name1"] = $name1;
        $_SESSION["name2"] = $name2;
        $_SESSION["surname1"] = $surname1;
        $_SESSION["surname2"] = $surname2;

        $_SESSION["sec"] = $page;
```

Page Two (Recive Page One)

```
<?php
session_start();
$id      = (isset($_SESSION["id_user"]))      ? $_SESSION["id_user"]      : null;  
$name3    = (isset($_SESSION["name_user"]))    ? $_SESSION["name_user"]    : null;
$surname3    = (isset($_SESSION["surname_user"]))    ? $_SESSION["surname_user"]    : null;
$sec = (isset($_SESSION["sec"])) ? $_SESSION["sec"] : null;
$voti2 = (isset($_SESSION["voti2"])) ? $_SESSION["voti2"] : null;
$voti1 = (isset($_SESSION["voti1"])) ? $_SESSION["voti1"] : null;
$code1 = (isset($_SESSION["code1"])) ? $_SESSION["code1"] : null;
$code2 = (isset($_SESSION["code2"])) ? $_SESSION["code2"] : null;
$name1 = (isset($_SESSION["name1"])) ? $_SESSION["name1"] : null;
$name2 = (isset($_SESSION["name2"])) ? $_SESSION["name2"] : null;
$surname1 = (isset($_SESSION["surname1"])) ? $_SESSION["surname1"] : null;
$surname2 = (isset($_SESSION["surname2"])) ? $_SESSION["surname2"] : null;

if (!empty($_SESSION["id_user"])) {
    $who = $name3 . " " . $surname3;
}

if (empty($code1)) {
    $code = $code2;
    $vote = $voti2+1;
    $name = $name2;
    $surname = $surname2;
} else {
    $code = $code1;
    $vote = $voti1+1;
    $name = $name1;
    $surname = $surname1;
}

unset($_SESSION["voti1"]);
unset($_SESSION["voti2"]);
unset($_SESSION["code1"]);
unset($_SESSION["code2"]);
unset($_SESSION["name1"]);
unset($_SESSION["name2"]);
unset($_SESSION["surname1"]);
unset($_SESSION["surname2"]);
unset($_SESSION["sec"]);
```

I have two page, one set the variables and two recive them to save in a DB.
Oage one extract query data from the Table and set in Session-Variables, Page two recive them, insert them into the new Table and after destry them.
Don't give any error, but don't work, why?

Comment: I see no `session_start()` on page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably with missing the `session_start();` statement in page one.
Use debugging statements like `print_r($_SESSION)` or `var_dump($_SESSION)` in second page to see weather it carries the data you need to inserted in table.

- **off topic** but important: **don't use mysql_* functions. [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**

Answer (score 4):

In page one, `session_start();` is missing. You need to add that.

Answer (score 1):

Because Session Needs To Be Open In Page One Also,

You Can Add `var_dump($_SSESION);` In Page One ,

And See What it will print of `NULL` Only Add `session_start();` To The Top OF Page One

Cause You Need To Make Sure That The Server Understand That You Still In The Same Scoop

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `sessoin_start();` in page one